# Typescript - Can I "bolt-on" types from one module to another module?

Tags: node.js, typescript, browserify

**Background**

Node has a package called `path` which has a type definitions file associated with it in the `@types/node` npm package. Someone made a client-side package called `path-browserify` which has the *same api* but has no types.

**Question**

Can I *bolt on* the `@types/node` types for `path` to use with `path-browserify`? Basically I want to use types in one place with a different name. I've tried this:

```js
// types.d.ts
declare module 'path-browserify' {
  export {default} from 'path'
}

// usage.ts
import * as path from 'path-browserify'

const joined = path.join('/', 'file');
// ^ COMPILE ERROR: join not found

const joined = path.default('/', 'file'); 
// ^ RUNTIME ERROR: default not found
```

But I'm unable to access the api correctly. Is there a better way to use these type definitions? preferably without copying the `path` api.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You look like you're on the right track. Can you do something like this?

```
declare module 'path-browserify' {
  import path from 'path'
  export default path
}
```

As for your usage, try the following (rather than using `* as` syntax)

```
import path from 'path-browserify'
path.resolve(...)
```

As an aside, does the `path` module even have a default export ... ?

Comment: Thanks mate, your answer worked exactly as I wanted!